# Where do I put onWindowBeforeUnload?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a SAP UI5 application and I would like to show a box that appears when the user tries to navigate away from the screen through methods outside my application (clicking on links, manually changing URL, etc).

I see there is a `onWindowBeforeUnload()` method but I am not sure where I put this method or how it gets called. I tried including it in my controller that I want the functionality in but it does not get called when I navigate away. If there's any other function that can provide this behavior, that'll be fine too.

Here's what I did in my controller:

```
onWindowBeforeUnload: function() {
    alert("you sure?");
},
```

I see that this is a method of the component class but I thought this was created in the beginning; I am not too familiar with this concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can override it directly from your controller. You'll either have to override it on the window object itself (as per @matt-spinks' answer above) or override it on your Component.js file (if you are using one).

Here's how to do it on the Component.js file:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/UIComponent"], function (UIComponent) {
    "use strict";
    return UIComponent.extend("company.main.Component", {
        // ...
        // ...

        /**
         * Fired before the window closes or moved to another URL
         */
        onWindowBeforeUnload: function(oEvent) {
            // your code
        },

        /**
         * Fired when the window is closed.
         */
        onWindowUnload: function(oEvent) {
            // your code
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: And would you know how I could only call that function if it's on a certain view? I have a master detail type of application. Whenever they click on an item in the master, a detailed view comes up with more information on that item. I want the detailed view to have this behavior.

Comment: I actually don't need it for a certain view immediately, the example you showed worked fine, thank you! If you do know how to check which view I am on though it'll be helpful.

Comment: Getting the current view is a tad bit tricky. What I usually do is get the current URL hash and then figure out the route that is used on that hash. You can get the routes you defined on your manifest via:

`
var aAllRoutes = this.getManifestEntry("/sap.ui5/routing/routes")
`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different ways of doing it:

in the body tag

`<body onbeforeunload='alert("no!!")'>`

in your js code:

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      alert('no!!');
    }
</script>
```

Make sure to use `window.onbeforeunload` and not `onWindowBeforeUnload`.

Also, make sure you put the code within  tags in the rendered output of your page, or inside an included javascript file. Based on what your code looks like, it sounds like you are using a javascript library, which is why you are using `functionName: function(){ //body }`. You cannot use that method to override the `window.onbeforeunload` function, because you are trying to handle the function inside a sub-node of window. You have to use the top-level window node and handle the function there. And you can do that by putting this code directly inside `<script>` tags or the body tag.

Comment: for your js code example, where exactly do I place that? The way you wrote it makes it look like I write inside another function. Every other function I have defined has the following syntax  in my controller `functionName: function(){ //body },`

Comment: Perhaps we need a bit of context. With my example, you would put the code within `<script>` tags in the rendered output of your page, or inside an included javascript file. Based on what you just told me, however, it sounds like you are using a javascript library, which is why you are using `functionName: function(){ //body }`. You cannot use that method to override the `window.onbeforeunload` function, because you are trying to handle the function inside a sub-node of window.

Comment: You have to use the top-level window node and handle the function there. And you can do that by putting this code directly inside `<script>` tags or the body tag.

Comment: Yes, the context is a SAP UI5 Application. I don't think I should put code inside a `<script>` tag because I can only see putting that in the index.html and I don't think it'd make sense to put code there. But if you know about UI5 design then maybe you can correct me?